# JAXB XML Creation

Tags: xml, jaxb, schema, xjc

I have following class

```java
@XmlRootElement
Class A{

    private int id;
    private String name;

    //getter and setter

}
```

I want to create schema and xml for this class where XML can have list of Class A but I dont want to create another class which contains a list of class A. Is there any annotation to tell JAXB that the generated schema and xml will have unbounded list of A objects.

Any help would be appreciated!!!!!

Comment: How do you want your XML schema to look?